# Php Mysql - check variables duplication with empty command

Tags: php, mysqli

i have user add form in my webpage.

Codes like this;

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']) ==1) {

        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['name']);
        $surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['surname']);
        $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['date']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['password']);
        $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['city']);

        $q = "INSERT INTO users (name, surname, date, email, password, city) VALUES('$name', '$surname', '$date', '$email', '$password', '$city')";
        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q); 


    if($r) {
        $message = 'User was added';
    }else{
        $message = 'User could not be added because: '.mysqli_error($dbc);
        $message .= '<p>'.$q.'</p>';
        }
    }
```

my submit button is:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add User</button>
<?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; }?>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
```

I want to check existing values in my database table with that post button.
How can i check same values in this post?

Comment: what souldn't be the same ?

Comment: before add do a select with `emailId` if not available then add else give message like already existing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitted']) == 1) {

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['name']);
    $surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['surname']);
    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['date']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['password']);
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['city']);

    $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$email."'";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

    if ($r->num_rows == 0) {
        $q = "INSERT INTO users (name, surname, date, email, password, city) VALUES('$name', '$surname', '$date', '$email', '$password', '$city')";
        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

        if ($r) {
            $message = 'User was added';
        } else {
            $message = 'User could not be added because: ' . mysqli_error($dbc);
            $message .= '<p>' . $q . '</p>';
        }
    } else {
        $message = "Email does exist already";
    }
}
```

Comment: in your select email is `undefined`... it will give mysql error.

Comment: @Suchit and now ?

Comment: What are you doing , you should allow to insert if `$r->num_rows == 0`. Please test your code before posting.